# Nvidia Dual Displays not being detected

Tags: nvidia, display

I just installed Ubuntu for the first time, downloaded 11.04 and updated to 11.10.
I have a setup with a NVidia 7600GT Graphics Card, with DVI-Out and VGA-Out. I have two displays connected to those plugs, and they work perfectly on windows.
I updated to NVidia's latest driver with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates  
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

and i still can't get Ubuntu to recognize i have two displays...

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Does system preferences -> screen -> detect monitors help? If not try to create xorg.conf file and add manually second monitor. Do You know how to do it?

Comment: system preferences -> screen -> detect monitors -- that's what i am doing without success. i don't know how to create that file and add the second monitor...

Comment: Tried `sudo nvidia-settings` yet? Might have to install nvidia-settings though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To configure your two monitors manually,

stop your display manager:

```
sudo stop gdm
```

if the process is not found, try `ps -ax | grep dm` to look for your manager.

press:

```
Alt+Ctrl+F1
```

and log in. After that create xorg.conf file:

```
sudo Xorg -configure
```

The contents of the file should be written on the screen and the path to the created file should be written also (path depends on how You are logged, as super user or as Your user and just using sudo command)

Edit created xorg.conf.new (it is created instead of xorg.conf, but it is the same):

```
sudo gedit xorg.conf.new
```

You should find sections responsible for screen card and monitor. In my case these are:

```
Section "Monitor"
    #DisplaySize      380   300
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "AOC"
    ModelName    "919"
    HorizSync    30.0 - 80.0
    VertRefresh  55.0 - 75.0
    Option      "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "radeon"
    VendorName  "ATI Technologies Inc"
    BoardName   "Radeon 2100"
    BusID       "PCI:1:5:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Copy Your monitor and screen sections and paste it somewhere in that file, and name (change Identifier) them Monitor1 and Screen1.

In Screen section corresponding to Screen1 change used monitor to Monitor1

```
Monitor "Monitor1"
```

reboot and then try to go to system->preferences->screen and detect monitors.

Comment: when i run, sudo stop gdm i get unknown job... when i run Xort - configure i get Fatal server error: Server is already active for display 0

Comment: What desktop manager do You use? Gnome?

Comment: it's the  default one when i install ubuntu 11.10, Unity i think

Comment: so try: sudo service stop gdm  and then the rest

Comment: You get sudo: stop: command not found

Answer (score 7):

Open `nvidia-settings` and configure it there.

The proprietary driver does not integrate very well with Ubuntu's system settings.

Comment: thanks, when i run that and select XServer Display Configuration, i get Unable to load X Server Display Configuration page: Failed to query NoScanout for screen 0. And on the menu, i only see X Screen 0